# How can I add PHP-FPM with nginx?

Tags: nginx

Currently I'm using nginx with HHVM but for some reasons HHVM crashs alot
What I'm trying to do is:

Rplace HHVM with php-fpm

OR

Add php-fpm as fallback

PS: I used this to install nginx + HHVM:
https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 0):

I have made this [simple script](https://github.com/ThemisB/hhvm_nginx_installer/blob/master/setup.sh) to install latest `HHVM/Nginx/MySQL`, at once, depending on different Ubuntu Distros. Binaries that are used, come from the official repos that the HHVM team uses. Check `var/log/hhvm`, `error.log` file and create issue if you think it is a HHVM.

I use `HHVM` on servers, and it rarely crashes.